# Is there a quick way to horizontally scroll in VimDiff with word-wrap?

Tags: vimdiff

VimDiff seems to be a useful tool, but I can't seem to find a way of quickly and efficiently scrolling horizontally when word-wrap is set to "off". I am currently using "zh" and "zl" but they only work per click.

I'd rather not use sublime for diffing, but I just might have to!

Answer (score 1):

There are other options than just `zh` and `zl`; check out `zH` and `zL` to jump half screen at a time, or `zs` and `ze` to move to the start and end of the line, respectively.

Even better, if your limitation is worst during when using `vim -d`: set the windows to all scroll together with `:scrollbind` (check out all the options with `:help scrollbind`).

Curious: is it work that does not let you use word wrapping, and why?  :)

I don't know if this would work, but `:setglobal textwidth=foo` (or `:setlocal`) might also be useful, given your limitations ...

Answer (score 0):

you can remap Shif-MouseWheel events to horizontal scroll in .vimrc:

```
map <S-ScrollWheelUp> <ScrollWheelLeft>
map <S-ScrollWheelDown> <ScrollWheelRight>
```

So MouseWheel will move vertically and Shift+MouseWheel will scroll horizontally